# How can I find the earliest date from a set of rows identified by the same ID number?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to figure out the right formula to copy the earliest date into a new column only if excel can identify that the same ID number in the row and the same ID numbers in column A are all scanned in the process.

So column A might have five rows of REQ100 all with varying dates. I would like another column added that scans all of those REQ100s and pulls out the earliest date into my new column.

I would like to do the same in another column for the latest date.

So far I have been trying MIN(IF... and MAX(IF... with no luck. Even trying the Control+Shift+Enter function to paste the formula into my spreadsheet isn't returning accurate results. [Please click here for pictorial example of data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rjGY.png)

Answer (score 2):

Enter this as an array formula (Ctrl-Shift-Enter):

```
=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$100=$A2,$B$2:$B$100))
```